# Is it necessary that the reply to office action be made by attorney

Tags: examination, attorney

I am asking in connection with USPTO filing.

Lets say my patent is filed by a US attorney (I am not a US citizen).
Now it goes through examination, and office action is sent.

I want to know is it legally necessary that my entire office actions will be handled by the attorney only?
Can I send the replies directly now?

Answer (score 2):

You are free to retract the Power of Attorney you signed and take over the case but you will need to do that before you send in anything. The USPTO will not deal with you while your attorney is still empowered. Also you can change attorneys. There is no requirement to stick with the practitioner who originally filed.

Writing a patent well is hard for a layman but so is responding to an office action.